# How to extract the value of an neighbour attribute node via XPath?

Tags: xpath

I have two different web pages and I want to extract some value using XPath.
What request can extract *2386028* from the first page and at the same time can extract *4019606* from the second page? I need one request that can universally extract that values.

First page fragment:

```
    <ul class="g-ul b-properties">
        <li class="b-properties__header">General</li>
        <li class="b-properties__item">
            <span class="b-properties__label">
                <span>VendorCode</span>
            </span>
            <span class="b-properties__value">2386028</span>
        </li>
        <li class="b-properties__item">...</li>
        <li class="b-properties__item">...</li>
        <li class="b-properties__item">...</li>
```

and second  page fragment:

```
<div class="b-properties-holder" id="tab_3">

    <ul class="g-ul b-properties">
        <li class="b-properties__header">General</li>
        <li class="b-properties__item">
            <span class="b-properties__label">
                <span>Trademark</span>
            </span>
            <span class="b-properties__value">
                <a class="link b-properties-link" href="/trademark/moist-diane/?sort=-date&amp;currency=USD">Moist Diane</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="b-properties__item">
            <span class="b-properties__label">
                <span>VendorCode</span>
            </span>
            <span class="b-properties__value">4019606</span>
        </li>
        <li class="b-properties__item">...</li>
        <li class="b-properties__item">...</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the `<li>` element, which has `<span class="b-properties__label">`element that contains `<span>` with value `VendorCode`, and then get value of `<span class="b-properties__value">` under that `<li>` element.

For example:

```
//li[span[@class="b-properties__label"]/span="VendorCode"]/span[@class="b-properties__value"]/text()
```

Alternatively, you can select the `<span class="b-properties__label">`element , which has `<span>` with value `VendorCode`, and get its following sibling.

```
//span[@class="b-properties__label" and span="VendorCode"]/following-sibling::span/text()
```